# Error while running WCF service library

Tags: wcf, serialization, service

I have built a WCF service library, I have added reference to few 3rd party dll's. This is my interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    3rdpartyreturntype GetObj(System.Windows.Controls.Control txtcontrol);
}

// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
[DataContract]
public class nclass
{
    [DataMember]
    public System.Windows.Controls.Control txtcontrol
    {
        get { return txtcontrol; }
        set { txtcontrol = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public 3rdpartyreturntype nobj
    {
        get { return vuiobj; }
        set { vuiobj = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice tchdev
    {
        get { return tchdev; }
        set { tchdev = value; }
    }
}
```

and I have implemented the above interface. When I run the service I get the below error, can anyone help me out?

> type 'System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute.

Comment: Can you write wrappers for all of the 3rdpartyreturntype?  If so, then those can be marked with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a complex type like a class to be serialized you have to declare each of its members as data member and class as datacontract.

In this case touch device is the complex type(class) so you need to mark all of its members as datamembers and class as datacontract.

but as i can see from type that it belongs to system.windows.input the class may not be serialized. hence you cannot use this as a data member.

If you are using only a set of members belonging to touchDevice class, you can create your own class which will map only the set of touchdevice members which can be serialized. and decorate this new class with datacontract and datamember attributes.

Comment: GetObj method is a 3rd party method and the parameter they are expecting is System.Windows.Controls.Control, so i cant change that. Also i added touch device only because i was getting it in the error,i am not using it anywhere (maybe 3rd part dll is using it am not sure). Also i used reflector and had a look at the 3rd party class "3rdpartyreturntype" if i can map its members into my own class and serialize that class. but from what i see, one of its property is a service. Do i have to map all the properties? how can i map a service?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the type "System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice" is itself not marked as serializable or a DataContract.

Instead of trying to pass the TouchDevice and the Control directly like that, maybe you can just pass the properties you care about.  I'm guessing in the case of the TextControl you just care about the Text value.  And for the TouchDevice, maybe the source and target control name?

Comment: GetObj method is a 3rd party method and the parameter they are expecting is System.Windows.Controls.Control, so i cant change that. Also i added touch device only because i was getting it in the error,i am not using it anywhere (maybe 3rd part dll is using it am not sure). Also i used reflector and had a look at the 3rd party class "3rdpartyreturntype" if i can map its members into my own class and serialize that class. but from what i see, one of its property is a service. Do i have to map all the properties? how can i map a service?